# How to update the existing rows add insert new rows in table in laravel for multiple array values

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

i have a table of data with array input values , as like below

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="user_id[]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="user_id[]" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="user_id[]" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="user_id[]" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone[]"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And i m trying to update the first two rows with `user_id` value and trying to insert last two rows as new rows.
I m using the below insert query in laravel controller :

```
if(!empty(Input::get('user_id')))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count(Input::get('name')); $i++) 
    {

        $id   = Input::get('user_id')[$i];
        $data = User::find($id);
        $data->name          = Input::get('name')[$i];
        $data->email         = Input::get('email')[$i];
        $data->phone         = Input::get('phone')[$i];
        $data->save();
  }
}

if(empty(Input::get('user_id')))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count(Input::get('name')); $i++) 
    {
        $new                = new User();
        $new->name          = Input::get('name')[$i];
        $new->email         = Input::get('email')[$i];
        $new->phone         = Input::get('phone')[$i];
        $new->save();
  }
}
```

But its not working properly . can somebody suggest me any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `foreach` loop to, well, loop through the fields and do something if it is empty or not.

Maybe, something like this would help you.

```
$fields = Input::get('user_id');

foreach($fields as $field)
{
    if(! empty($field))
    {
        // field is not empty
        // update here
    }
    else
    {
        // field is empty
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Great ! Even i was working with the same flow , worked . Thank you